# Openlayers3 map stretch when resizing browser window

Tags: openlayers

When resizing the browser window, the map image is enlarged or stretched in the resize direction when renderer is set to webgl or canvas, but not with DOM.
This can be seen on this example:
http://openlayers.org/en/v3.10.1/examples/side-by-side.html?q=render

Where does this comes from, and is there a way to prevent this appart with DOM renderer?

Comment: Using the example you provide, I have exactly the same attitude on all type of renderes. I use latest version of firefox. I havent test it with any other browser.

Answer (score 2):

it is an open issue now
https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/issues/1963

There are some tricks and one of them is 
https://jsfiddle.net/GeospatialMax/9dyx8mjL/ 
by GeovationMax